# Delay on client side query - Meteor's Mongo Collections

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am a Meteor newb and I am trying a simple collection query on the client side. I declared the `Subject` collection in a common.js file in the root, so the files in both the `client/` and `server/` folders have access to it.

Problem: When I want to display some `Subject` data in my `home` template through the `drop` helper, the data gets shown and then disappears.
With a console.log in my helper definition I see the data appearing in the following order, with a ~20sec delay between the loggings.

1. `[]`
2. `[Object]`
3. `[]`
4. `[Object]`

If I query the server, the result is fast and correct.
My Object looks like:

```
{"_id":"b97SpxtduH2spqLXw","id":"15920","upd":"2013-12-29 04:42:16","uuid":"be81554a-7759-11e4-adb6-57ce06b062da","term_id":"9000","lang":"en","part_speech":"","gender":"","term":"Terminologia Morphologica","source":"","description":"","wiki":"","email":""}]
```

I've already stripped my code to what I've shown you. I have the `autopublish` package but I keep getting this delay when I query on the client side. When I do a simple `console.log` of the query inside  client.js I get `undefined`.

[Edit2:] meteor remove udondan:bulk-collection-update did the job. Thank you.
[Edit:] I've tried removing all other packages, reinstalling meteor, trying another browser (Chrome 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit), Safari 8.0). I am on Yosemite OS X Version 10.10.1.
root/subject.html:

```
<template name="home">
  {{#each drop}}
    Smth {{this.term}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

root/common.js:

```
Subject = new Mongo.Collection("subject");
```

client/client.js:

```
Template.home.helpers({
  drop: function () {
    var c = Subject.find({uuid: "be81554a-7759-11e4-adb6-57ce06b062da", lang: "en"}).fetch();
    console.log(c);
    return c;
  }
});
```

My meteor packages:

```
Users-MBP:subject user$ meteor list
accounts-github                 1.0.2  Login service for Github accounts
accounts-google                 1.0.2  Login service for Google accounts
accounts-twitter                1.0.2  Login service for Twitter accounts
accounts-ui                     1.1.3  Simple templates to add login widgets ...
autopublish                     1.0.1  Publish the entire database to all cli...
insecure                        1.0.1  Allow all database writes by default
iron:router                     1.0.3  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
meteor-platform                 1.2.0  Include a standard set of Meteor packa...
nooitaf:semantic-ui             1.1.2  Semantic UI packaged for Meteor
udondan:bulk-collection-update  0.2.0  Bulk insert/update/delete documents in...
```

Comment: I put your code into [a meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/Mqq94E4EYCk6FJod6/Clientside%20find) and it works fine.  I haven't added the packages you list so maybe one of them causes the issue.

Comment: As I said in my edit: I've tried removing all other packages, reinstalling meteor, trying another browser (Chrome 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit), Safari 8.0). I am on Yosemite OS X Version 10.10.1.

Comment: Yes, you were right ... It seems that somehow I always used the bulk-collection-update package ( @Ron was right ) even when I removed all others. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks great for me too.

```
meteor remove udondan:bulk-collection-update
```

Deletes the bulk-collection-update package. Does it work then?

Comment: Actually this solved it. I probably forgot to try without this exact package because I always used it to initialize my db. Thank you!

Comment: Great! :)

Actually, you don't have to init your db. Meteor is doing it for you when you type `meteor` in your project root directory.

With `udondan:bulk-collection-update` package you can update/replace the whole content of a collection with the content of an array. Nothing more, nothing less. 

After a quick look up i think it doesn't init something for you. :)